# Why was I suspended?

Tags: discussion

Moderators please don't disclose my personal detail.

I can't find moderator message, but it about bounty? I think I messaged back moderators, but got no reply. But Tim Post moderator said it's OK if I place a bounty on the post of a friend/relative.

[Is it OK if I place a bounty on the post of a friend/relative? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175455/is-it-ok-if-i-place-a-bounty-on-the-post-of-a-friend-relative)

> People put too much faith in an IP address being identifiable. It's very common for an ISP to put its clients behind a NAT, thousands of people can share the same outgoing IP. Every time someone says "they have the same IP" I ask if they also have the same eye color. But, I digress.
>
> It's your rep - spend it like you want. While conceivable that the bounty system, in conjunction with association bonuses could be used over time to help build up a sock puppet, that's an extremely corner case. If you want to add a bounty to your friend's question in order for it to receive an answer, there's absolutely no problem with that.
>
> Likewise, there'd be no problem placing a bounty to reward an excellent answer that a friend wrote. Again, it's your rep. When the bounty system is used, someone's rep inflates as someone's rep deflates. It's not like they're earning reputation that wasn't 'there' to begin with, as they would with votes. Plus, it's completely open and over the table - everyone sees it.
>
> If you place a bounty on a .. shall we say .. *less than good* question, you'd probably get some strange looks, but hey - it's your rep :)

Comment: Does your case match the "friend/relative" example, or sock puppet accounts you control? Asking for a friend. :)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea not sockpuppet

Comment: Because you constantly break the rules. Simple!

Comment: @curiousdannii which rules?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to see past moderator messages in your global inbox: [How do we see the private messages that moderators sent us?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/how-do-we-see-the-private-messages-that-moderators-sent-us)

On StackExchange it's not allowed to use multiple accounts to do something that can't be done with a single account: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Why bring up sockpuppets? why didn't you read  quote?

Comment: @PamelaLee you can contact the Community Managers here if you're unhappy with moderator decisions: https://money.stackexchange.com/contact